# SOA Composite deployment taking long time, sending servers in critical state

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, oracle-fusion-middleware, soa-suite, oracle-enterprise-manager

I recently deployed a soa composite application on em (Enterprise Manager) but it took 1 hour to deploy (it got deployed successfully after an hour) which resulted in admin and other server to go in critical state.
I tried the same in lower environment but the deployment took less then a minute
Few points:
I double cross checked the configuration plan that was used with the jar, its correct.
The jar was tested in lower envmt before deploying to higher envmt.

What can be the reasons for long deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Did the problem just emerge with this composite and all other composites deploy as expected?
Can you create a test composite  - input a file and output via a mediator and does it deploy as expected? if so - then there is a problem with you original composite. If not then there's a problem with your install.